# Make [angular-testing] a synonym of [angular-test]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Below are the current tag information

> **[angular-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-testing)** (*262 questions*)
> Use when dealing with Questions related to testing Angular applications, when a test fails, or when unable to solve an issue about **testing a component or service or any other angular element**. *This tag is similar in use to this other SO tag: [angular-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-test)*.

> **[angular-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-test)** (*412 questions*)
> **Questions about testing Angular code**, addressing either specific issues ("why is this test failing"), test flows ("how to test this async call of my component"), or test setup ("how do I mock router in this component test"), integration tests ("how to bypass a proxy to my backend in this angular test"), or possibly test-related questions, such as ("Why does this component work and the test is failing?").

Number of questions tagged with **both** tags : *106 questions*

[angular-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-test) is just an alternate phrase for [angular-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-testing) both used on questions about testing an angular application

Below are the top ten tags that have been used together with this tag

| TAG | [angular-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-testing) and [angular-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-test) | [angular-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-testing) | [angular-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-test) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) | 94 | 298 | 360 |
| [jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine) | 27 | 64 | 98 |
| [karma-jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karma-jasmine) | 26 | 70 | 114 |
| [unit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) | 12 | 33 | 67 |
| [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) | 9 | 27 | 46 |
| [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) | 5 | 18 | 21 |
| [angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6) | 5 | 24 | 18 |
| [angular8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular8) | 4 | 9 | 14 |
| [karma-runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karma-runner) | 4 | 13 | 15 |
| [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) | 3 | 8 | 22 |

If we do a correlation of the [angular-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-testing) and [angular-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-test) columns we get a correlation of **0.99197**, an indication that these two tags are highly correlated

Comment: Honestly, I think we should delete them both. Questions should be tagged [angular] + [unit-testing] or [angular] + [e2e-testing]. Or possibly, now that I think further, [angular] + [karma] or [jest] or [angular] + [protractor] or [cypress]. The fact that "testing" is involved is really irrelevant. What's relevant are the libraries being used for that.